# How do the WinAPI Shell APIs differ from the base API and CRT functions?

Tags: windows, api, winapi, process

I was reading through Windows process APIs, and was left with three questions:

1. What is the difference between base APIs and shell APIs? I read that shell APIs wrap base APIs e.g. ShellExecute() and ShellExecuteEx() wrap CreateProcess() but fail to understand the distinction.
2. How are base APIs and Shell APIs different from CRT functions (C Runtime). As again, exec() and spawn() CRT functions wrap CreateProcess() of the base API.
3. I understand that I can use base APIs and CRT functions from code directly by compiling and linking with the correct header files. How do I make use of Shell APIs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1) What is the difference between base API's and shell API's?**

They do different things.  ShellExecute family does things in the same way as the shell, i.e. in the same way as windows explorer. It is not simply a wrapper around CreateProcess. For example, if you pass to ShellExecute the path to a word document, ShellExecute will look up in the registry to find out what is the correct way to open a word document, and do that.

ShellExecute can also do the other "verbs" you see on the Windows context menu, such as edit, print, etc.

**2) How are base API's and Shell API's different from CRT functions**

CRT functions are implemented on Windows so as to be compatible with the C standard. They are wrappers around CreateProcess, but the reason they exist is to be compatible not to offer additional functionality.

**3) How do I make use of Shell API's**

To use the shell APIs you simply include the header files and link the correct library, just as with any other API.

For example, ShellExecute:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx

As you see at the bottom of the page it tells you which file to include and which library to link against.

> Requirements
>
> Minimum supported client:  Windows XP [desktop apps only]
>
> Minimum supported server:  Windows 2000 Server [desktop apps only]
>
> Header:  Shellapi.h
>
> Library:  Shell32.lib
>
> DLL:  Shell32.dll (version 3.51 or later)
>
> Unicode and ANSI names: ShellExecuteW (Unicode) and ShellExecuteA
>   (ANSI)

Answer (score 1):

The shell (aka Windows Explorer) adds an extra layer of functionality.  It manages *file associations*, it knows what EXE should be started when you ask it to "run" a document.  If you pass the name of, say, a .html file then ShellExecuteEx() can figure out that a browser needs to be started.  It also supports *verbs*, different things you can do with a document.  Other than "open", the default verb, the "print" and "edit" verbs are common for example.

That's missing from CreateProcess(), it only knows how to start an executable file.  Still with lots of options, review the MSDN docs for the security attributes and creation flag options.

Lots of those whistles are missing from the CRT functions, they work on any operating system so you cannot do much beyond specifying the executable name and the command line arguments.